# How to send data to webpage using Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, python-requests

**CONTEXT**

I created this python flask application. It reads csv file, calculates the 'data' from that file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')


def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def index_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req = request.form['fileToUpload']
        df = pandas.read_csv(req)
        base_pay_MEAN = df['BasePay'].mean()
        overtime_MAX = df['OvertimePay'].max()
        highest_paid_Person_NAME = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == max(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['EmployeeName']
        highest_paid_Person_SALARY = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == max(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['TotalPayBenefits']
        num_Unique_Jobs = df['JobTitle'].nunique()
        most_common_jobs = df.groupby('JobTitle').count().sort_values(by='Id', ascending=False)['Id'].head(3)        
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Here's part of the HTML file

```
            <p>Please upload your CSV file. The values containing addresses should be in a column named <em>address</em> or <em>Address</em></p>
            <form method='POST'>
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <button id="download">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div class="results">
                <h3 class="base-pay"></h3>
                <p class="base-pay-mean"> </p>
                <p class="base-pay-high"></p>
                <p class="base-pay-low"></p>

                <h3 class="over-time"></h3>
                <p class="over-time-max"></p>

                <h3 class="highest-paid"></h3>
                <p class="highest-paid-person"></p>
                <p class="highest-paid-job"></p>
                <p class="highest-paid-salary"></p>


                <h3 class="lowest-paid"></h3>
                <p class="lowest-paid-person"></p>
                <p class="lowest-paid-job"></p>
                <p class="lowest-paid-salary"></p>
            </div>
```

Here's image of the webpage: [image]

**PROBLEM**

I already calculated the values that I need to send back to the webpage, such as base_pay_MEAN, overtime_MAX etc. I already created a `<div>` with `class = "results"` and I need to send this data to the corresponding tags in that div. But how do I send it back to the webpage? 
My goal is when the user uploads a CSV file and clicks submit, the page should show the necessary values such as: [image]

But I'm even sure where to begin.

ps. Sorry of long post

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values you want to display as keyword arguments to [`render_template()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

For example, to show "Basepay Mean", you would send the appropriate variable to the template from your view (the Python part):

```
base_pay_MEAN = df['BasePay'].mean()
return render_template('index.html', base_pay_MEAN=base_pay_MEAN)
```

And then render that variable in the template (the HTML part):

```
<div class="results">
    <h3 class="base-pay">Basepay:</h3>
    <p class="base-pay-mean">Mean: {{ base_pay_MEAN }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make a dictionary and return it via

```py
return jsonify(response_dict)
```

(you will need to import the function `from flask import jsonify`).

The response `dict` in my case was

```py
response_dict = {"message" : reponse_text}
```

as it was done here https://medium.com/zenofai/creating-chatbot-using-python-flask-d6947d8ef805

```py
@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    message = request.form['message']
    project_id = os.getenv('DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID')
    fulfillment_text = detect_intent_texts(project_id, "unique", message, 'en')
    response_text = { "message":  fulfillment_text }
    return jsonify(response_text)
```